# find minimum sum of non-neighbouring K entries inside an array

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an integer array `A` of size `N`, find minimum sum of K non-neighboring entries (entries cant be adjacent to one another, for example, if K was 2, you cant add A[2], A[3] and call it minimum sum, even if it was, because those are adjacent/neighboring to one another), example:

```
A[] = {355, 46, 203, 140, 28}, k = 2, result would be 74 (46 + 28)

A[] = {9, 4, 0, 9, 14, 7, 1}, k = 3, result would be 10 (9 + 0 + 1)
```

The problem is somewhat similar to [House Robber](https://leetcode.com/problems/house-robber/) on leetcode, except instead of finding maximum sum of non-adjacent entries, we are tasked to find the minimum sum and with constraint K entries.

From my prespective, this is clearly a dynamic programming problem, so i tried to break down the problem recursively and implemented something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int minimal_k(vector<int>& nums, int i, int k)
{
    if (i == 0) return nums[0];
    if (i < 0 || !k) return 0;
    return min(minimal_k(nums, i - 2, k - 1) + nums[i], minimal_k(nums, i - 1, k));
}
int main()
{
    // example above
    vector<int> nums{9, 4, 0, 9, 14, 7, 1};
    cout << minimal_k(nums, nums.size() - 1, 3);
    // output is 4, wrong answer
}
```

This was my attempt at the solution, I have played around a lot with this but no luck, so what would be a solution to this problem?

Comment: Is your solution incorrect or suboptimal?

Comment: _"I have played around a lot with this but no luck"_ does not adequately describe what you did or what issues you are facing.  Given the verbosity with which you described the task and the code, I'm surprised that you then fail to explain the actual problem with which you require assistance.

Comment: Please explain why 4 is wrong. Also add more examples of non-working cases, their wrong output and what in the taks decription they contradict. Did you find any cases in which the otput is correct? When debugging, is there a special situation in which the occurring intermediate values differ from those you expect? When playing around, did some of the variants you tried exhibit any enlighteningly different misbehaviour?

Comment: @Yunnosch k is 3, how did you get 4 from summing 3 different elements in that example? as for other cases, i tried multiple ones and used a memo and most of the time it just returns the single minimum element of the array as a result in each entry of the memo, ex : A[] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2}, k = 3, output is 1

Comment: You are not asking me how I came up with 4, do you? Also, please [edit] information and explanation into the question.

Comment: @Yunnosch this was just my personal attempt it could be very wrong, i never said this solution works, im here asking for the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
if (i < 0 || !k) return 0;
```

If `k` is 0, you should probably return return 0.  But if `i < 0` or if the effective length of the array is less than k, you probably need to return a VERY LARGE value such that the summed result goes higher than any valid solution.

In my solution, I have the recursion return `INT_MAX` as a long long when recursing into an invalid subset or when `k` exceeds the remaining length.

And as with any of these dynamic programming and recursion problems, a cache of results so that you don't repeat the same recursive search will help out a bunch. This will speed things up by several orders of magnitude for very large input sets.

Here's my solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// the "cache" is a map from offset to another map
// that tracks k to a final result.
typedef unordered_map<size_t, unordered_map<size_t, long long>> CACHE_MAP;

bool get_cache_result(const CACHE_MAP& cache, size_t offset, size_t k, long long& result);
void insert_into_cache(CACHE_MAP& cache, size_t offset, size_t k, long long result);


long long minimal_k_impl(const vector<int>& nums, size_t offset, size_t k, CACHE_MAP& cache)
{
    long long result = INT_MAX;
    size_t len = nums.size();

    if (k == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (offset >= len)
    {
        return INT_MAX; // exceeded array boundary, return INT_MAX
    }

    size_t effective_length = len - offset;

    // If we have more k than remaining elements, return INT_MAX to indicate
    // that this recursion is invalid
    // you might be able to reduce to checking (effective_length/2+1 < k)
    if ( (effective_length < k)  ||  ((effective_length == k) && (k != 1)) )
    {
        return INT_MAX;
    }

    if (get_cache_result(cache, offset, k, result))
    {
        return result;
    }

    long long sum1 = nums[offset] + minimal_k_impl(nums, offset + 2, k - 1, cache);
    long long sum2 = minimal_k_impl(nums, offset + 1, k, cache);
    result = std::min(sum1, sum2);

    insert_into_cache(cache, offset, k, result);

    return result;
}

long long minimal_k(const vector<int>& nums, size_t k)
{
    CACHE_MAP cache;
    return minimal_k_impl(nums, 0, k, cache);
}


bool get_cache_result(const CACHE_MAP& cache, size_t offset, size_t k, long long& result)
{
    // effectively this code does this:
    // result = cache[offset][k]

    bool ret = false;
    auto itor1 = cache.find(offset);
    if (itor1 != cache.end())
    {
        auto& inner_map = itor1->second;
        auto itor2 = inner_map.find(k);
        if (itor2 != inner_map.end())
        {
            ret = true;
            result = itor2->second;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

void insert_into_cache(CACHE_MAP& cache, size_t offset, size_t k, long long result)
{
    cache[offset][k] = result;
}


int main()
{
    vector<int> nums1{ 355, 46, 203, 140, 28 };
    vector<int> nums2{ 9, 4, 0, 9, 14, 7, 1 };
    vector<int> nums3{8,6,7,5,3,0,9,5,5,5,1,2,9,-10};

    long long result = minimal_k(nums1,  2);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    result = minimal_k(nums2, 3);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    result = minimal_k(nums3, 3);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be much easier for readers if you actually explained your algorithm

Comment: I cleaned up the code and added a few more comments.

Comment: it works for all test cases i have, "you probably need to return a VERY LARGE" i think this was the key when going out of bounds, there is also a subtle bug in my solution with the if statement "(nums[i] == 0)" where i return nums[0], thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is core sorting related problem. To find sum of minimum k non adjacent elements requires minimum value elements to bring next to each other by sorting. Let's see this sorting approach,

Given input array = `[9, 4, 0, 9, 14, 7, 1]` and `k = 3`
Create another array which contains elements of input array with indexes as showed below,
[`9`, 0], [`4`, 1], [`0`, 2], [`9`, 3], [`14`, 4], [`7`, 5], [`1`, 6]
then sort this array.
Motive behind this element and index array is, after sorting information of index of each element will not be lost.
One more array is required to keep record of used indexes, so initial view of information after sorting is as showed below,

```
Element and Index array
..............................
| 0 | 1 | 4 | 7 | 9 | 9 | 14 |
..............................
  2   6   1   5   3   0   4    <-- Index   

Used index record array
..............................
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
..............................
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6    <-- Index
```

In used index record array `0 (false)` means element at this index is not included yet in minimum sum.
Front element of sorted array is minimum value element and we include it for minimum sum and update used index record array to indicate that this element is used, as showed below,
font element is `0` at index `2` and due to this set `1(true)` at index `2` of used index record array showed below,

```
min sum = 0

Used index record array
..............................
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
..............................
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

iterate to next element in sorted array and as you can see above it is `1` and have index `6`. To include `1` in minimum sum we have to find, is left or right adjacent element of `1` already used or not, so `1` has index `6` and it is last element in input array it means we only have to check if value of index `5` is already used or not, and this can be done by looking at used index record array, and as showed above `usedIndexRerocd[5] = 0` so `1` can be considered for minimum sum. After using `1`, state updated to following,

```
min sum = 0 + 1

Used index record array
..............................
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
..............................
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

than iterate to next element which is `4` at index `1` but this can not be considered because element at index `0` is already used, same happen with elements `7, 9` because these are at index `5, 3` respectively and adjacent to used elements.
Finally iterating to `9` at index = `0` and by looking at used index record array `usedIndexRecordArray[1] = 0` and that's why `9` can be included in minimum sum and final state reached to following,

```
min sum = 0 + 1 + 9

Used index record array
..............................
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
..............................
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

Finally `minimum sum = 10`,
One of the **Worst case** scenario when input array is already sorted then at least `2*k - 1` elements have to be iterated to find minimum sum of non adjacent `k` elements as showed below
input array = `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` and `k = 4`
 then following highlighted elements shall be considered for minimum sum,
[`1`, 2, `3`, 4, `5`, 6, `7`, 8, 9, 10]
**Note**: You have to include all input validation, like one of the validation is, if you want to find minimum sum of `k` non adjacent elements then input should have at least `2*k - 1` elements. I am not including these validations because i am aware of all input constraints of problem.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cout;

long minSumOfNonAdjacentKEntries(std::size_t k, const std::vector<int>& arr){

    if(arr.size() < 2){
        return 0;
    }

    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::size_t>> numIndexArr;
    numIndexArr.reserve(arr.size());

    for(std::size_t i = 0, arrSize = arr.size(); i < arrSize; ++i){

        numIndexArr.emplace_back(arr[i], i);
    }

    std::sort(numIndexArr.begin(), numIndexArr.end(), [](const std::pair<int, std::size_t>& a,
              const std::pair<int, std::size_t>& b){return a.first < b.first;});

    long minSum = numIndexArr.front().first;

    std::size_t elementCount = 1;
    std::size_t lastIndex = arr.size() - 1;

    std::vector<bool> usedIndexRecord(arr.size(), false);

    usedIndexRecord[numIndexArr.front().second] = true;

    for(std::vector<std::pair<int, std::size_t>>::const_iterator it = numIndexArr.cbegin() + 1,
        endIt = numIndexArr.cend(); elementCount < k && endIt != it; ++it){

        bool leftAdjacentElementUsed = (0 == it->second) ? false : usedIndexRecord[it->second - 1];
        bool rightAdjacentElementUsed = (lastIndex == it->second) ? false : usedIndexRecord[it->second + 1];

        if(!leftAdjacentElementUsed && !rightAdjacentElementUsed){

            minSum += it->first;

            ++elementCount;
            usedIndexRecord[it->second] = true;
        }
    }

    return minSum;
}

int main(){

    cout<< "k = 2, [355, 46, 203, 140, 28], min sum = "<< minSumOfNonAdjacentKEntries(2, {355, 46, 203, 140, 28})
        << '\n';

    cout<< "k = 3, [9, 4, 0, 9, 14, 7, 1], min sum = "<< minSumOfNonAdjacentKEntries(3, {9, 4, 0, 9, 14, 7, 1})
        << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
k = 2, [355, 46, 203, 140, 28], min sum = 74
k = 3, [9, 4, 0, 9, 14, 7, 1], min sum = 10
```